# FTDI USB to Serial (Biocontrol HHR scanner Device) on Windows IOT

Tags: uwp, raspberry-pi, ftdi, windows-iot-core-10

I am trying to get a specific device (details below) to register/connect via usb/serial (FTDI) on a Raspberry Pi 3 (with Windows IOT Core v15063). I am quite new to the Pi and IOT world so I was first trying to replicate the connection using the Microsoft UWP samples. Works perfect, sends data etc, on UWP on Win10 desktop.

[UWP on Win10 PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16XLD.png)
(its the last item - FTDIBUS... via COM3)

But on the RPi, the device (via FTDI BUS) is not detected...
[UWP on Pi/Win10IOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7wOM.png)

There is suggestion here of some level of support for FTDI from Windows IOT blog:

> We have also included an in-box driver for the FTDI USB-to-serial
>   chipset because many devices use that as the interface port for
>   controlling them (for example, Home Automation Systems). Just plugging
>   these devices in will now have them register as an available serial
>   port.

**Device**: BioControl HHR 3000 Pro V2

I am specifically trying to connect it via usb/serial as the device needs to be mounted unattended and bluetooth connection seems less reliable, plus extra cost for bluetooth capabilities on the device so potentially more cost effective over usb/serial.

Is there something I have missed?

Comment: Can you show the following information: 1. Connect your HHR to raspberry pi and use this command to check the driver:`devcon status =usb`. 2. Connect your HHR device to desktop and go to Device Manager->Ports->COM3->Properties->Driver->Driver Details->Driver files.

Comment: **Windows PC**
system32..
\drivers\tfser2k.sys
\drivers\serenum.sys 
\ftcserco.dll
\ftserui2.dll

**On Pi***
USB\VID_040E&PID_0100&DWCHSOTGHUB\0
    Name: DwcHsOtg USB Root Hub
    Driver is running.
USB\VID_0424&PID_9514&DWCHSOTGHUB\4&B947FD8&0&1
    Name: Generic USB Hub
    Driver is running.
ACPI\BCM2848\0
    Name: Microsoft DWCHSOTG USB Host Controller
    Driver is running.
3 matching device(s) found.

Comment: Just to add, at one point it did come up in the device manager as USB\VID_19FC&PID_0002\HHR2 statuscode 25191424, problemcode 28, but strangely it is not coming up again...

Comment: From your info on Pi, it looks like the FTDI driver is not running. Make sure the driver file `ftdibus.sys` is in this path on your Pi:`C:\Windows\System32\Drivers`.

Comment: Yes it is in that directory     Directory: C:\windows\system32\drivers


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       2017/08/01     03:32          75176 ftdibus.sys